# Iterating through html array is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried iterating through this but could not.
the function below
function orderpackage (){

```
var product_line = $('#carttable')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 1; i < product_line.length; i++) {
}

console.log(product_line)
```

Produces this in the console output

[image]

each of the tr.table_row is made from this

```
<tr class="table_row">
  <td class="column-1">
    <div class="how-itemcart1">
      <img src=${Items.imageurl} alt="IMG">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="column-2">${Items.name}</td>
  <td class="column-3">$ ${Items.price}</td>
  <td class="column-4">
    <div class="wrap-num-product flex-w m-l-auto m-r-0">
      <div class="btn-num-product-down cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m qty-change" id="qty-change">
        <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>
      </div>

      <input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product" type="number" name="num-product1" value=${Items.user_quantity}>

      <div class="btn-num-product-up cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m qty-change" id="qty-change">
        <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="column-5">${line_total_sum}</td>
</tr>
```

what I want to do is iterate through each and get the price, quantity and line total.
When I tried the function below for the line total is shows error

```
var product_line = $('#carttable')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[4];
```

How do I iterate through each tr to the price, quantity and line total?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery selectors with DOM methods?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery... `$.each(product_line, function(index, item){ //do something with the item and/or index} );`

Comment: Well the iteration will happen within your `for()` loop so if you add something like `console.log(product_line[i]);` I am sure you will see it log individual elements. That is why your current attempt isn't logging each item but as suggested above, you might be better using `jQuery` since you have the library loaded/in use.

Comment: @NewToJS I did that, I just did not include it. the problem is that, it does not output anything. So i thought maybe it has to do with HTMLCollection

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give an example of the rendered output of the table and the `javascript` you have tried so far? Also explain what your expected output/goal is please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain JS, you can use [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) to get all the rows on the table.

Then you need to iterate over them, probably skipping the first one (header). For each one, access the children (cells) that contain the fields you need and create a new array with them, `[price, quantity, total]`, and push that one to another array containing the data for all the table.

Here's one way to do it using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const tableData = Array.from(document.getElementById('table').rows).slice(1).map(row => {
  const cells = row.children;
  
  return [cells[0].innerText, cells[1].innerText, cells[2].innerText];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableData));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: right;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><th>PRICE</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>32</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you prefer to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead:

```js
let tableData = [];

// Iterate over every row:
for (const row of document.getElementById('table').rows) {
  // Get the cells in the current row:
  const cells = row.children;
  
  // Read the text on the columns we want:
  tableData.push([cells[0].innerText, cells[1].innerText, cells[2].innerText]);
}

// Remove the first row (header):
tableData = tableData.slice(1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableData));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: right;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><th>PRICE</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>32</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or just a normal [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop instead:

```js
const rows = document.getElementById('table').rows;
const totalRows = rows.length;
const tableData = [];

// Iterate over every row, skipping the first one (header) already:
for (let i = 1; i < totalRows; ++i) {
  // Get the cells in the current row:
  const cells = rows[i].children;
  
  // Read the text on the columns we want:
  tableData.push([cells[0].innerText, cells[1].innerText, cells[2].innerText]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableData));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: right;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><th>PRICE</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>32</td></tr>
</table>
```